# Volley: No authentication challenges found

Tags: java, android, android-volley, misfit

I'm using Volley in an Android App to fetch data from the Misfit API (http://build.misfit.com). I tried to construct an intermittent activity, after someone logged in, to get all the data from the API. In that activity, I perform a JsonObject GET request, that should give me some information about the user of the app. Here's the code so far:

```
package com.iss_fitness.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import learn2crack.weboauth2.R;

public class LoadingScreenActivity extends Activity {

    //Introduce an delay
    private final int WAIT_TIME = 500;
    private static final String QUERY_URL = "https://api.misfitwearables.com/move/resource/v1/user/me/profile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("LoadingScreenActivity  screen started");
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
        findViewById(R.id.mainSpinner1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executeJson();
                System.out.println("Going to Profile Data");
                /* Create an Intent that will start the ProfileData-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoadingScreenActivity.this, DataView.class);
                LoadingScreenActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                LoadingScreenActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, WAIT_TIME);
    }

    private Response.ErrorListener createRequestErrorListener() {

        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        };
    }

    private void executeJson() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("AppPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String token = prefs.getString("token", null);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        System.out.println(token);
        params.put("access_token", token);
        CustomRequest jsonRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.GET, QUERY_URL, params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.println(response);
                    }
                }, this.createRequestErrorListener());
        System.out.println(jsonRequest);
        queue.add(jsonRequest);
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to Android development, so please bear with me, I'll try to describe the code. I've implemented a help class as suggested for JsonObjectRequest, as, as I understood, you can't override the getparams method when defining a request locally. the executeJson() method is the interesting one: I get the user access token from my SharedPreferences (Where it's correctly stored), put that in a String Map and give that to the CustomRequest, where, inside the help class, it gets thrown into a getparams method that simply returns the params. The responselistener sadly never gets called, as the errorlistener reports the following:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
```

According to the API reference of Misfit, that should work.
Now, I know that a GET request requires "headers" and not "params" but does that make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. The helper class contained an overriding getparams method, but no getheaders method. GET request requires getheaders, post requires getparams.